# Format for ebook that contains code

Tags: conversion, markdown

What's a good format for making an ebook that contains code. Is markdown a good option or is there something better available? I may want to convert it to ePub/Mobi and PDF later.

Is it a good idea to add custom styles to markdown files? Would these styles play well with softwares like pandoc?

What other options do I have?

**Edit**

The book is about prolog and will contain mainly these types of structure:

- Headings- h1, h2, h3 ...
- Paragraphs
- Tables (**without** headers)
- Indented Text
- Code Snippets
- Big example code blocks which may contain text and code or just code (ranging from 15 to +100 lines). I need these parts to look different from code snippets.

Comment: Do you mean source code in some programming language? Or e.g. encrypted data.

Comment: I mean Source code

Comment: Markdown -> pandoc -> Sigil seem to be a decent pipeline. Stylesheets can be added by pandoc or manually later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Embedding code in EPUB can be accomplished with pure HTML and CSS. The `<code>` tag and `monospace` attribute will bring you most of the way. See https://github.com/oreillymedia/HTMLBook for a lot of detail.

Comment: For backwards compatibility with older readers, <pre><code>stuff here</code></pre> might be a good idea - if I recall, some older devices don't like the <code> tag, also font selection through CSS might fail for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Markdown to do that, but it is not in my experience, the best option. Reason for this is that what you should really do is incorporate the code from from real programs that can be tested using some (unit-)test harness. 
That way there is far less chance that the code you include in your book contains some error that would go unnoticed because it was never run.

markdown is however kept very simple and does not support inclusions of code from somewhere else.

- There are ways around that limitation using `pandoc`, as it allows merging of files as it allows merging of files, but for including code snippets of a few lines at a time that is a bit too course to my liking, and you loose the overview in your markdown text where goes what.
- There are other add-ons for markdown to [assemble](http://assemble.io/docs/Markdown.html) that keep the include information within the file. You would need to somehow generate the snippets of code to include in your text in separate files and include them.

If you have anything more than a few snippets you should look at the [reStructuredText format](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html), and especially its use within [sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/). It was particularly written to document source code. Originally for Python but also supporting other programming languages. It has native support for the including/assembling.

Sphinx has build in support for epub and pdf generation, the latter without having to go through LaTeX. With `pandoc`, you would have to use LaTeX which is not always trivial to set up, depending on your OS.

Comment: rST looks interesting. The code in the book won't change very often so I won't need to include source files. I updated the question. For the last point, is there a neat way to do this in rST?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to include long blocks of code, maybe the simplest way is to use some form of styled html/xhtml where you will define that code text will use a fixed width font, that you usually should include. Starting from html will make subsequent conversion very easy.

If you have to include long blocks of code, maybe there are better solutions, but I'm not very helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LaTeX. Packages like [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [minted](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) can be used to include code snippets and syntax highlighting. Both are supported by `tex4ht`, so conversion to html and then epub is possible. And as bonus, you can get perfect PDF file.

If you are interested, I have a sample document (in Czech language, but I hope the code is readable) where packages `minted` for syntax highlighting, `biblatex` for bibliographies, and `glossaries` for acronyms were used: [TeX source](https://github.com/michal-h21/abcclanek/blob/master/abcclanek.tex) and [generated html](http://michal-h21.github.io/abcclanek/abcclanek.html). For conversion, [make4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht) was used. `make4ht` is frontend for `tex4ht` which allow you to use your own [build scripts](https://github.com/michal-h21/abcclanek/blob/master/abcclanek.mk4) and it has some filters for generated html cleanup.

There is also another tool, [tex4ebook](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook), based on `make4ht`, which can be used to convert `LaTeX` to `epub`, `epub3` and `mobi` formats. Note that I am the author of `make4ht` and `tex4ebook`.

Answer (score 1):

Leanpub might be a solution. See [this section](https://leanpub.com/help/manual#leanpub-auto-code) (html) of their manual on code snippets. If you have a lot of code you can put it in an external file and reference it. Leanpub uses markdown and a dropbox folder you share with Leanpub for each book. It generates pdf, epub and mobi so it seems perfect for what you want to do. Their Syntax highligher, [pygments](http://pygments.org/languages) supports prolog.

The only downside I have found is the way it handles images. The images have to be at least 300PPI (pixels per inch) so unless you want your book to be huge you have to limit how many images you use. The images look terrible if they are less than 300 PPI.